# Need to relabel a custom link in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, custom-link

I have a custom link in my org that I want to add to the Homepage.  I'm doing this via Lightning App Builder by using the link button and adding the URL.  Is there a way to relabel this link so it is pretty and not a long URL?  In Classic, the label I gave it during creation is what's displayed but in Lightning App Builder, I don't see an option to do this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using standard component **Rich Text** Box in Lightning App Builder. First drag the standard component Rich Text on the home page. Add the Label Text in the editor and make it hyperlink using the Link button in the editor menu. Refer the image below.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you!